# HttpServletRequest.getParameter losing parameter

Tags: java, servlets

I am confused that the HttpServletRequest.getParameter will return null sometimes while I really include the parameter in my request.

Test program below:

HelloServlet.java:

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static Executor logExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        logExecutor.execute(new Task(req));
    }
}

class Task implements Runnable {
    private HttpServletRequest req;

    public Task(HttpServletRequest req) {
        this.req = req;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(String.format("a=%s b=%s c=%s",
                req.getParameter("a"), req.getParameter("b"),
                req.getParameter("c")));
    }
}
```

Map this servlet to /hello in the web.xml

Start the servlet in tomcat or jetty, launch the request with the shell scripts:

```
#/bin/sh

for i in {1..100}
do
        curl -i -X GET "http://localhost:8080/hello?a=a&b=b&c=c"
done
```

the server log shows that some parameter in some request maybe null and this case occured with no regular pattern. Such as:

```
a=a b=b c=c
a=a b=b c=c
a=null b=null c=null
a=null b=null c=null
a=null b=null c=null
a=null b=b c=c
a=null b=null c=c
a=a b=b c=c
a=a b=b c=c
a=a b=b c=c
a=a b=b c=c
a=null b=null c=null
a=a b=b c=c
a=null b=b c=c
```

I found the reason is that I cannot hold the HttpServletRequest instance for my Executor.
So I want to know the reason why! Why the action I hold a HttpServletRequest instance in one requst may affect the other requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, I think you can not access request parameters once it has finished.

You are passing the `HttpServletRequest` to a `Thread`. Sometimes it'll be executed before the request has finished and sometimes later. Therefore, sometimes you get the parameters and sometimes they are `null`.

Avoid handling `HttpServletRequest` outside `doGet` or `doPost`. You should copy the information from the original request into a separate data structure for later processing.

For example:

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static Executor logExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String data = String.format("a=%s b=%s c=%s",
                req.getParameter("a"), req.getParameter("b"),
                req.getParameter("c"));
        logExecutor.execute(new Task(data));
    }
}

class Task implements Runnable {
    private String data;

    public Task(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Extract from [Java Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/):

> *3.11 Lifetime of the Request Object*
>
> **Each request object is valid only within the scope of a servlet’s service method, or within the scope of a filter’s doFilter method**,
>   unless the asynchronous processing is enabled for the component and
>   the startAsync method is invoked on the request object. In the case
>   where asynchronous processing occurs, the request object remains valid
>   until complete is invoked on the AsyncContext. **Containers commonly
>   recycle request objects in order to avoid the performance overhead of
>   request object creation.** The developer must be aware that
>   maintaining references to request objects for which startAsync has not
>   been called outside the scope described above is not recommended as it
>   may have indeterminate results.

Comment: I am curious Why a HttpServletRequest instance's value may be affected by other requests.

Comment: I'm not saying that HttpServletRequest can be affected by another one. But once the request has finished (response is send to the client), the application server (tomcat, jetty... ) may clear it's data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are redeclaring the variable `req` in the `Task` class here:

```
private HttpServletRequest req;
```

- So your `req` variable here isn't even initialized, and has nothing
  to do with the servlet request.
- Also I can't see where you are setting those parameters to the request, so where did you set    parameters `a,b and c` to the request or to the req variable?